# A java method returning a java.util.Map generates a String return in openapi instead of a Map

Tags: java, openapi

I generate an `OpenAPI` json from a Java REST service, in a class. It's method returns a `java.util.Map`.

```java
@Operation(description = "Retourne les communes du Code Officiel Geographique en vigueur une année particulière.")
@RequestMapping(value = "/communes", method=RequestMethod.GET)
@ApiResponses(value = {
     @ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "Communes présentes sur le territoire cette année là, sous la forme d'une Map<String, Commune>.",
           content = {@Content(schema = @Schema(implementation = Map.class))}
     ),
     @ApiResponse(responseCode = "500", description = "Un incident est survenu durant l'extraction des communes.")
   }
)   
public Map<String, Commune> obtenirCommunes(
   @Parameter(name = "anneeCOG", description = "Année du Code Officiel Géographique.", example = "2019")
   @RequestParam(name="anneeCOG") int anneeCOG) throws TechniqueException {
   CodeOfficielGeographique cog = this.cogService.obtenirCodeOfficielGeographique(this.session, anneeCOG);

   return cog.getCommunesAsMap();
}
```

But the json produced doesn't describe a Map for return type for my method :

```
"/cog/communes":{
"get":{"tags":["cog-controller"],
"description":"Retourne les communes du Code Officiel Geographique en vigueur une année particulière.",
"operationId":"obtenirCommunes", "parameters":
[{"name":"anneeCOG","in":"query",
"description":"Année du Code Officiel Géographique.",
"required":true,"schema":{"type":"integer","format":"int32"},"example":2019}],
"responses":{"500":{"description":"Un incident est survenu durant l'extraction des communes.",
"content":{"*/*":{"schema":{"type":"object","additionalProperties":{"$ref":"#/components/schemas/Commune"}}}}},
"200":{"description":"Communes présentes sur le territoire cette année là, sous la forme d'une Map<String, Commune>.",
"content":{"*/*":{"schema":{"type":"string"}}}}}}}
```

instead, it returns a `"schema":{"type":"string"}`.

What have I done wrong ?

- Is it the `content = {@Content(schema = @Schema(implementation = Map.class))}` I have put along with `responseCode = "200"` that is wrong ?
- Am I lacking an annotation ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This annotation was responsible of my trouble.

```java
@ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "Communes présentes sur le territoire cette année là, sous la forme d'une Map<String, Commune>.",
  content = {@Content(schema = @Schema(implementation = Map.class))}
),
```

The content :

`content = {@Content(schema = @Schema(implementation = Map.class))}`

has to be removed.